# Four space characters in the beginning of a random name HTTP header

Tags: node.js, http, security, http-protocols

I've discovered a domain name (web site and API) which adds a header like this to each HTTP response:

```
    XTVOpalL: Gtm; path=/; Max-Age=900
```

The header name looks random. Here are few other examples:

```
    XRQOJalT: LtZ; path=/; Max-Age=900
    XYjOzalA: Ntx; path=/; Max-Age=900
    XykOMalm: ytD; path=/; Max-Age=900
```

Note the leading 4 spaces. And compare to other response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 05 May 2018 11:52:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://example.com/wp/
Content-Length: 229
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_993094=GuEL85vzTDKQUJ9jfphhgvma7VoAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACgWz3NlkG3smvkXeB6Ewyl; expires=Sun, 05 May 2019 08:21:45 GMT; path=/; Domain=.example.com
Set-Cookie: nlbi_993094=z0NWEcMl0wAVBr8CiwzebQAAAACu2KRRlrUCoWpyWKTrUAJF; path=/; Domain=.example.com
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_115_993094=/xoUXc5Kags3fAFBHpCYAfma7VoAAAAABT/i1XAh1J4D/02wGnXO9w==; path=/; Domain=.example.com
Set-Cookie: ___utmvmicuVtwf=peInjtBXhca; path=/; Max-Age=900
Set-Cookie: ___utmvaicuVtwf=wYxmyOU; path=/; Max-Age=900
Set-Cookie: ___utmvbicuVtwf=TZr
    XYjOzalA: Ntx; path=/; Max-Age=900
X-Iinfo: 13-63374213-63374214 NNNN CT(222 -1 0) RT(1525521145044 0) q(0 0 2 0) r(5 5) U11
X-CDN: Incapsula
```

Main problem - this header sometimes is the **first** header in the response. Which, in turn, is considered a vulnerability.

In my case it looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    XYjOzalA: Ntx; path=/; Max-Age=900
Date: Sat, 05 May 2018 11:52:25 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://example.com/wp/
...
```

Quoting the RFC of HTTP 1.1 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3

> A sender MUST NOT send whitespace between the start-line and the first header field.
> ...

> The presence of such whitespace in a request might be an attempt to
> trick a server into ignoring that field or processing the line after
> it as a new request, either of which might result in a security
> vulnerability if other implementations within the request chain
> interpret the same message differently.  Likewise, the presence of
> such whitespace in a response might be ignored by some clients or
> cause others to cease parsing.

This results in node.js throwing error trying to parse these HTTP responses. Error code is `HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN`, which is thrown only if HTTP headers are malformed.

Question: What is it? Who's doing it? Why?

Comment: Can you share the URL of that web site or API?

Comment: @shaochuancs I can't share mine, but can share two other examples I found in the wild: https://tradebeam.com.websiteoutlook.com/ and https://asgaur.com.websiteoutlook.com/

Comment: @shaochuancs note that my website have this random header as the first header in the response. The two examples I gave have the header somewhere in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 2):

*"What is it?"*

This is a bug in server side, as it violates HTTP protocol.

Actually, it was [discussed](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2013JanMar/1166.html) in HTTP working group in 2013 for "a bug into python library", and I think the [conclusion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2013JanMar/1167.html) by [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) is correct:

> It's not a legal field name, thus not a legal start of a header field line.
>
> ...
>
> It's forbidden by the grammar, so it's invalid.

*"Who's doing it? Why?"*

When developer generate the random HTTP header name, he/she introduces this 4-whitespace leading characters, by accident.

Comment: Developers of the API checked everything they could (code, nginx, WAF, etc). They are not adding these headers. At least intentionally. So, I would have to disagree that the answer to the "Who?" question is "developer generate".